# An inequality involving a trigonometric series

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

For a natural number $N$, suppose it holds that
$$
N \leq \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{\cos(\theta_j + \theta)}{\cos(\theta)},
$$
where $\theta$ can be either positive or negative, but can be chosen to be close to $0$. What can I say about the $\theta_j$'s? Should they also be small? Can one obtain a bound on $|\theta_j|$?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT.
One could also consider the inequality
$$
N \leq (1+\delta) \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{\cos(\theta_j + \theta)}{\cos(\theta)},
$$
where $\delta>0$ can be small, but not dependent on $N$. 
What can I say, then, about the  $\theta_j$'s?

Comment: Should the inequality hold for all $\theta$ or just for a given $\theta$ ?

Comment: One $\theta$ could do.

Comment: I don't know that there's going to be a very nice answer. Since $\cos(\theta)$ is just a constant, this is basically equivalent to solving $\sum\cos(\theta_i)\geq a$ for some $a$, and the answer is just that you take the pre-image under $\cos$ of the half-space $\{x\in\mathbb R^N\mid\sum x\geq a\}$.